# LED doesn't completely turn off with digitalWrite(led, LOW);

Tags: arduino-ide, led, nodemcu, button, digitalwrite

When I was testing out a program I found a strange behavior of ESP8266.

LEDs don't turn off completely in the first `digitalWrite(led, LOW)`, just the brightness of the LED goes down, but it does turn off in the second `digitalWrite(led, LOW)`.

I don't know if it's related to the code or the circuit, so here are both (the program is just two different visual patterns of LEDs toggled by a button)

```
#define led1 D0
#define led2 D1
#define led3 D2
#define led4 D3
#define button D7

unsigned long pressedButton;
bool change = 0;
unsigned long previousTime = millis();
unsigned int difference;


void setup() {
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
}


void loop(){
  if (!digitalRead(button) && millis()-pressedButton>200){       //check if button was pressed to change visual pattern of leds
      pressedButton = millis();
      change = !change;
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);         //here led completely turn off
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
      previousTime = millis();
  }

  difference = millis()-previousTime;
  
  if (!change){                                     //default visual pattern of leds
    if (!digitalRead(led1) && difference>=200){
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    }
    if (!digitalRead(led2) && difference>=400){
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    }
    if (!digitalRead(led3) && difference>=600){
      digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }
    if (!digitalRead(led4) && difference>=800){ 
      digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    }
    if (difference>=1000){
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW);           //the leds just shrink here
    }
    if (difference>=1200){
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    }
    if (difference>=1400){
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
    }
    if (difference>=1600){
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
      previousTime = millis();
    }
  }
  
  if (change){                    //alternative pattern
     if (!digitalRead(led1) && difference>=200 && change){
       digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
       digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    }
    if (digitalRead(led1) && difference>=400 && change){
       digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
       digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
       digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
       previousTime = millis();
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
Actually, it's a NodeMCU Esp8266, with the pins defined on the code and a 470 ohms resistor.  (obs: resistor is not shorted, in my breadboard those rows are separated)

Comment: That resistor won't do anything with the conductor running underneath it in parallel.

Comment: `Leds doesn't turn off completely` ... how do you know this? ... maybe they are turning on and off very fast ... reduce your code to turn on led, delay 1 second, turn off led, delay 1 second, and repeat

Comment: have you checked the connection between wires and tried a new led?

Comment: @timemage Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my breadboard the bottom row is separated for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c++
if (!digitalRead(led3) && difference>=600){
  digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
}
if (!digitalRead(led4) && difference>=800){ 
  digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
}
if (difference>=1000){
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);           //the leds just shrink here
}
if (difference>=1200){
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
}
```

Consider what will happen when the difference is >= 1000.

If the LED is off you turn it on (because it passes the first test, the difference is >= 600), and a moment later you turn it off. So the LEDs are being turned on and off in quick succession, which makes them look dim.

Try re-ordering the tests, and add `else` for each subsequent one. That seems to work for me:

```c++
  if (!change){                                     //default visual pattern of leds
    if (difference>=1600){
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
      previousTime = millis();
    }
    else if (difference>=1400){
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
    }
    else if (difference>=1200){
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    }
    else if (difference>=1000){
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
    }
    else if (!digitalRead(led4) && difference>=800){ 
      digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    }
    else if (!digitalRead(led3) && difference>=600){
      digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }
    else if (!digitalRead(led2) && difference>=400){
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    }
    else if (!digitalRead(led1) && difference>=200){
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    }
  }
```

---

Also, that resistor on the bottom row isn't achieving anything because all the pins on the bottom row are connected together so it is just shorted out. Not good for the LEDs or the processor.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt see that problem on code. And sorry, I forgot to mention that my breadboard have the bottom row separated so it's not shorted.